Motherboard memory bus speed
I'm about to build a desktop PC first time in many years and I was confused by the following discrepancy related to memory speeds:

Zen5 CPUs "natively" support DDR5-5600 RAM (for example 9600X)
even faster DDR5 modules are available, I have seen at least DDR5-6400

Yet motherboards, even with the newest X870E chipset support only up to DDR5-5200 "natively" and require overclocking for higher speeds (for example the currently most expensive Gigabyte model X870E AORUS MASTER.
So my first question is what are the possible disadvantages of setting a motherboard's memory bus to an overclocked speed that is "natively" supported by both the CPU and the DDR5 modules I intend to purchase.
The second question is why is it so? What stops motherboard producers to "natively" support speeds that already are already "natively" supported by CPUs and DDR5 modules that these motherboards were designed for?
I put the word "natively" in quotes as I'm not sure if it's the right adjective to describe the speed at which a given component works without overclocking.
Update: specs from other manufacturers have been recently published and many of them do support 5600 "natively" (for example MSI Tomahawk).

These things are defined by the DDR5 Standards, and the associated XMP/EXPO specs, so the motherboard manufacturers are simply implementing these specs. I don't really consider XMP/EXPO to be overclocking anymore, but there are some circumstances that might prevent you from engaging with it, so I suppose they like to label it as "(OC)" just to make clear there are no guarantees it will work.

Please note that questions should have a single question. Currently your post contains multiple question. Are you aware of specific "disadvantages" that you want more information regarding, or are you just generally concerned? Please note that this site requires questions to be specific and practical, and asking for "possible disadvantages" does not meet this requirement. Why a given hardware piece does or doesn't support a specific standard is not something that can be answered with authority either. It could be as simple as the package was printed before that standard existed.

@FrankThomas so you are suggesting that these "OC" labels are  there to comply with Jedec naming (or some other standardization body), correct? I'm not sure if this is accurate as Jedec has defined DDR5 speeds up to 8800 as far as I understand the table on the right side of the Wikipedia page.

@music2myear I believe that these "multiple" (a big word for just 2) questions are very tightly related and will most probably be answered by the same set of reasons. I also believe that it is very practical to be able to correctly match and configure components when building a PC. Finally, no, I'm not aware of any specific disadvantages: that's the core of my question: not sure what's unclear about it...

@FrankThomas if both a CPU and a DDR5 module support a given speed without OC, what could possibly be other "circumstances that might prevent you from engaging with it"? Thanks! :)

Note that the wiki article says "Standard DDR5 memory speeds range from 4000 to 6400 million transfers per second (PC5-32000 to PC5-51200). Higher speeds may be added later, as happened with previous generations." so actual SPDs are not going to work for chips faster than PC5-51200 without extensions like XMP\EXPO which makes them "OC" by the manufacturers definition. as for "circumstances" I have a system with 4 exactly the same model dims that came in 2 packages. if I install any two from the same pack, I can XMP, but if I add the other two, it won't engage.

Before attempting to answer this question about "overclocking DDR5, and why it is so?", it is worth to get some excurse into the technology we are facing today. Here is the block diagram of DDR5 memory module from this article,

Aside the fact that DDR5 uses its own on-DMM voltage regulator(PMIC, and you can't play with voltages anymore), each of memory access busses (ChipSelect, Command/Address, DQ, and DQS) are trained over ranges of parameters including variation of timing, input voltage shapes, Tx voltage shape using multi-tap decision-feedback-equalization (DFE) technique to adjust for cross-talk and noise on the channels to have the best possible eye diagram opening.
Obviously, all these factors depend on particular mainboard design and quality of its PCB traces (channels) and materials. Every mainboard manufacturer performs exhaustive evaluation of memory modules from various suppliers, and provides a compatibility document for user convenience. Of course you may be lucky and your purchased memory module might work at out-of specs range, but I would't bet anything if your room temperature changes in any direction.
Now I hope you can answer your own questions after reading the referenced article.

Keep in mind the memory QVL is more of a guideline of what the manufacturer tested. A module of a certain frequency and timing delay, will give you an idea, if it will be compatible. At the end of the day, a single DDR5 module that isn’t listed on the QVL, that when compared to another equivalent specification module that was tested, will be compatible. I have a saying that goes DDR is DDR, at the end of the day, memory is memory and the entire purpose of manufacturing the memory is to sell memory.

Thanks for the answer! :) Would it be correct to summarize it like this: "Shortly speaking, designing and producing a memory bus that works reliably at higher speeds with all possible DDR5 modules by various manufacturers is even more difficult than producing a DDR5 module itself working at a given speed. This is because the DDR5 ecosystem is very complicated and kinda delicate as there are many factors and variables some of which are totally beyond the control by motherboard designers, fairly hard to predict and possibly expensive to circumvent."?

@morgwai, not exactly. You have an APU (Zen5), then you have a mainboard (read: transfer media), and you have a DDR5 DIMM. If the APU can theoretically drive and train itself at DDR-5600, it does not mean that, when coupled with a motherboard, it will be able to train at that speed. Apparently the mainboard designers can do their best at DDR-5200 speed, where they would guarantee the memory to work in specified temperature range and with certain memory brands (listed in their list). Motherboards do have cost factor, and this is the best they can do. But you can try, the training is flexible.
